# Getting custom options of configurable products

Tags: magento

How do you get the custom options of configurable products on checkout? For simple products, it is easy as:

```
foreach ($product->getOptions() as $option) {
    echo $option->getTitle();
}
```

where $product is a simple product.

However, this doesn’t work for configurable products.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?php
  if ($product->isConfigurable()) {
    $atts = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray($product);
    foreach($atts as $att) {
      echo $att['attribute_code'].": "
      $opts = $att['values'];
      foreach($opts as $opt) {
        echo $opt['store_label'].", ";
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks man looking this for a while! Custom options for configurable products. You are the man! :)